# Can a passenger request to visit the cockpit during a flight?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, pilots, cockpit, regulations

As a kid, I remember going to the cockpit of a plane with my mom (I believe the airline was [AOM French Airlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOM_French_Airlines)).

Is this still possible now?

I understand the answer might differ with different airlines/countries, I'm mostly interested in European and Asian airlines/countries, specifically Japanese.

Is there some specific regulations for international flights, or does it depends on departure/arrival locations?

Comment: [Related question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9259/19)

Comment: You can *ask*...

Comment: For EU and USA, this question has already been answered [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22744/12011). This is also a [related-ish question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20959/12011).

Comment: Pity they don't put a camera in the cockpit that I could watch as a channel on the in-flight entertainment system... with the audio channel hooked up to the radio.

Comment: @romkyns What, and have the passengers panicking because they've misinterpreted something the pilots said, or some minor problem with the plane as meaning OHMYGODWE'REGONNACRASH!!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This stopped after the World Trade Center attacks.

You might be able to get a kid in briefly before the plane takes off.

Comment: Or after it lands.

Comment: I know I did this as a kid before takeoff, and I'm pretty sure it was after 9/11.

Comment: @cpast Which company/origin/destination ?

Comment: @Antzi I think it was Delta; it was *years* ago, though, and I think I was still in elementary school at the time (i.e. like 10 years ago), and I don't remember origin/destination, other than "probably US domestic flight, because we don't go internationally that often". What I remember is that I got to see the cockpit, and I think the pilot let me request more printer paper, and I got a little set of "junior pilot" wings. That's about what I remember.

Comment: My eight year old daughter was in the cockpit of an A320 and an A330 on the same day a little less than a year ago. The A330 captain even gave her the flight map! Both were after landing, once in Spain and the second in Israel.

Comment: My guess is that it's easier to do this the younger the kid is.

Comment: This is inaccurate. As an adult, I visited the cockpit during a transatlantic flight in 2008. However, I did have to return to my seat before the plane arrived over Canada because of post-9/11 regulations.

Comment: I attended a talk by an A380 captain who works for BA. I asked him this question. His answer was a very enthusiastic "YES", but unfortunately only on the ground. He also said that he'd allow an adult just as well; doesn't have to be a kid. He was saddened that he could no longer let enthusiasts and especially aspiring children to experience the cockpit in flight.

Comment: @romkyns The problem is that before the flight, as the passengers file in, there are only a few minutes before take off and the crew is busy getting ready for departure. Thus, the window for a cockpit tour is pretty brief.

Comment: In the early/mid 90s, my parents and I had a flight where the first leg only had 3 passengers: us!  I clearly remember being in the cockpit with the pilots who had me help start the engines: when a certain gauge reached 20 I threw a lever all the way forward.
I'm pretty sure that post-9/11 this just wouldn't happen.

Comment: @cpast `"I know I did this as a kid before takeoff, and I'm pretty sure it was after 9/11."` This makes me feel old.

Comment: When I was getting my PPL (Pre 9/11) Air Canada let me ride in the jump seat for a half a flight from BOS-> YYZ that was amazing. More recently I got to sit in the pilot seat of an EasyJet flight from TLV->AMS while we were waiting for some weather to clear. I stuck my head in as I was boarding and said hi to the co-pilot. He invited me to do so.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, you will not get very lucky unless you are a pilot yourself and are carrying your license with you (and even then, this is airline dependent). If this is the case, you might even be able to ride in the jump seat for a portion of the flight

On the ground a lot of pilots/cabin crew are friendly and would be happy to show you around. Use common sense though and ask to go after landing for the best chance - before take off the crew will be quite busy with pre-flight checks.

Comment: By 'pilot' here do you mean 'airline pilot?' Most pilots, of course, are not airline pilots. Also, is there a specific area where you happen to know this to be the case? I have never heard of this being a possibility for private pilots here in the U.S., but if it is, I'd really like to know.

Comment: I'm based in South Africa and having a cursory glance at various local aviation forums, it appears that this happens occasionally here. From the language used, it appears learner pilots have the quite a bit of luck, with the airline pilots being happy to show the up and coming pilots what its like up front on a big jet and answer any questions they may have.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. You might want to edit your answer to include that information (specifically the parts about it being in South Africa and student pilots having a better chance.) Also, if you could include link some of the forum citations, that would be great. As a student pilot, this makes me want to visit South Africa. - lol

Answer (score 6):

Usually the cockpit is restricted during any phase of flight besides boarding/de boarding. This is usually the case with major airlines with any destination in Europe, or the U.S., not sure abut Asia though

Comment: As for Asia: No, same rule as US/Europe - except you know the right people, then it's possible... One of my wife's friends is a pilot of a major airline. We've been to his cockpit several times.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I ask to go to the cockpit **during** a flight ?

Of course you can. The answer will be a firm "No" and you will be watched very closely by the cabin crew and any plainclothes security onboard until you land. It's possible the police will be waiting for you.

> Can I ask to go to the cockpit **after** a flight ?

Of course you can. If it's a longer stop the crew are often happy to show off their office. If it's the end of a 12 hour intercontinental flight with a bad-weather landing they might decline.

Comment: I'm curious - can you provide any instances of the police talking to someone after landing due to a request to visit the cockpit?

Comment: @colti It wasn't in the media but I know a couple of years ago two student pilots had that treatment after asking to visit in flight. I do wonder if the police would have been called if they were white students...

Answer (score 3):

It's a *security and/or safety risk* to allow any persons in the cockpit these days.

[This accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot_Flight_593) happened as a pilot allowed his children to take control during flight.

> With the autopilot active, Kudrinsky, against regulations, let the children sit at the controls.

I've seen flight crashes, in which persons in the cockpit have interfered with the flight in one way or the other.

Based on these experiences, unauthorized persons in the cockpit is totally not allowed these days.

Comment: I think you can reference [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wider%C3%B8e_Flight_710) accident as well, if you want. "[The accident] was in part caused by the airline electing to not follow the Sterile Cockpit Rule and that a passenger was sitting in a cockpit jump seat during the flight."

Comment: 9/11 is *much* more significant here than Aeroflot 593.

Comment: You probably need to qualify that last sentence; those particular experiences did not drive changes in cockpit access; and it's clear from other answers here that it is not the case that unauthorized persons are "totally" not allowed in every cockpit.

Answer (score 3):

About 30 years ago I did this during flight when I was a kid. These days I manage to do it for my daughter but only while boarding.