# PIC Emergency Authority

Tags: faa-regulations, emergency, pic

Under 14 CFR 91.3 ---> ***"In an in-flight emergency requiring immediate action, the pilot in command may deviate from any rule of this part to the extent required to meet that emergency."***

Under which circumstances will that imply that the PIC deviate from Part 91?

Could it imply that Wx minimums won't apply?

Could it imply that Minimum Altitudes no longer are required?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/18882/62), maybe a dupe?

Answer (score 0):

> Could it imply that Wx minimums won't apply?

Yes

> Could it imply that Minimum Altitudes no longer are required?

Yes

Since both of those things are rules under part 91 (*"this part"*) specifically [91.155](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.155) 
and [91.119](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.119) you can indeed deviate from them as per 91.3.

The answer to "which circumstances" is far to broad to be defined in an all encompassing way which is why the FAA writes it the way they do.

Comment: A common sense rule of thumb is, if following a published rule or limit or mimimum means a higher risk of getting killed than not, then you do what you gotta do and any rule or regulation goes out the window.  You don't want to die for the sake of staying "legal".

Comment: @JohnK just make sure to close the window afterwards. The added noise and wind won't help with the emergency workload.